# express always routes to \

Tags: reactjs, express

**I have slash path as well as many routes still express goes to only slash route . Any help will be appreciated **

```
app.get("*", (req, res, next) => {
req.session.url = req.url;
console.log("requested *", req.session.url, req.url);
if (req.session.user == null) {
    console.log('Went to * SSo',req.session.url, req.url);
    res.redirect("/auth/sso");
} else {
    console.log('not to * SSo',req.session.url, req.url);
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
    if (req.session.url == '/' || req.session.url == '') {
        req.session.url = '/home'
    }
}
```

});

Comment: If this is your first request handler, then it looks like an infinite redirect loop.  If `req.session.user == null`, then you will do `res.redirect("/auth/sso")`, which will then immediately come right back in here and `req.session.user` is still not set so it will again `res.redirect("/auth/sso")` in an infinite redirect loop.  If you want further help, then show the context of the other relevant route handlers here.

Comment: It's a bit hard to see what your actual question is here, but if you're saying that everything gets routed to a request handler for `app.get("/", ...)`, then you have to show more code (including that route) so we can see how it gets there.

Comment: @jfriend00
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session.user == null) {
        console.log('Went to Slash SSo',req.session.url, req.url);
        req.session.url = req.url;
        res.redirect("/auth/sso");
    } else {
        console.log('not  to Slash SSo',req.session.url, req.url);
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
    }
});

Comment: Multiline code is not legible in comments here.  Please use the "edit" link below your question to edit the question, add the new code and then post a comment directed to me that you've added the code to the question.  Please also add some explanation for what this text in your question ***"I have slash path as well as many routes still express goes to only slash route"*** means.